# What do empty brackets inside a function mean?

Tags: javascript

I came across the following code and I'm curious what the `[]` means:

```
function checkForImage(mutation) {
        if (mutation.addedNodes && (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0)) {
            [].slice.call(mutation.addedNodes).forEach(function(node) { ...
```

Comment: I am assuming an empty array...

Comment: that's what i thought but i wasn't sure, thank you @dystroy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose is just to get an array (`[]` is an array) in order to be able to get the `slice` function.

This is necessary because `mutation.addedNodes` is probably "array-like" : array functions work but it's not an instance of `Array`. Here this construct with `slice` makes an array (so that the `forEach` function is available). This construct is common for example for live node lists. You can test it in the console on this page :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img').constructor // -> NodeList
document.getElementsByTagName('img').forEach // -> undefined
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).constructor // -> Array
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).forEach // -> a function
```

It could also have been

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(mutation.addedNodes).forEach(function(node) {
```

which would have avoided the creation of a useless instance (whose cost is probably ridiculously low) but would have been more verbose.

But a simpler and cleaner solution could have been

```
[].forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node) {
```

unless some hidden code justifies the use of a real array.

Comment: So in my instance does that mean that it is assigning an empty array to the checkForImage function, that will then be filled by the forEach?

Comment: No. The empty array's only purpose is to provide the `slice` function which is then used to clone `mutation.addedNodes` into an array. You can replace `[]` with `Array.prototype` in the code you show.

Comment: sorry i'm still trying to get a grasp on javascript prototype, but what does array.prototype do in this case? @dystroy

Comment: `Array.prototype` holds the function that all instances of `Array` will have. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain